# Unattended install of krb5-user on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory, ldap, kerberos

So, when running:

```
sudo apt-get install krb5-user
```

You are asked to enter the AD/LDAP domain. The problem is that I want this to be able to be run as a startup script for my machines. Is there any way to either pass the domain in as a parameter or disable the interaction and set up krb5-user after?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For an unattended installation try setting DEBIAN_FRONTEND variable to noninteractive with:

`export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

And pass the -y flag to apt-get:

`apt-get install -y krb5-user`

Comment: Ok, running `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y krb5-user` worked. I then had to update /etc/krb5.conf with:

`[libdefaults]
 default_realm = AD.MYDOMAIN.COM`

Thanks!

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 the accepted solution doesn't work (I recognize that the question is for 16.04).  For peeps on 18.04, first update /etc/krb5.conf as described by user6907792, and then apt install krb5-user -y.

Comment: @rcabr that seems to also help with 16.04 from what I can tell

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq install [packagename]
```

This worked for me without updating the `/etc/krb5.conf` on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This works well inside a shell script as well. If using `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` then running apt-get as sudo it doesn't pickup env change.