# Python error when running os.system("kinit") - sh: 1: kinit: not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, kerberos

I am building a python docker image and am testing out the kinit capability.  When I run the following `os.system('kinit') I am receiving an error

```
FROM python:3.5.7-buster

ADD krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf
ADD krb5.keytab /etc/krb5.keytab

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libsasl2-dev libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit openssl libkrb5-dev krb5-config kinit kinit-dev
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

Requirements:

`impyla==0.15.0 sasl==0.2.1 thrift_sasl==0.2.1 thriftpy==0.3.9 thriftpy2==0.4.0 numpy pandas openssl-python==0.1.1 kerberos`

Python code:

```
import ssl
from impala.dbapi import connect
import os

os.system("kinit")
```

I get the error `sh: 1: kinit: not found`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`kinit`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/kinit) Debian package is not-related to Kerberos:

```
# apt-cache search kinit
kinit - process launcher to speed up launching KDE applications
kinit-dev - process launcher to speed up launching KDE applications
```

The package that contains the `/usr/bin/kinit` binary is the [`krb5-user`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/krb5-user) package:

```
# dpkg -S /usr/bin/kinit
krb5-user: /usr/bin/kinit

# apt-cache search krb5-user
krb5-user - basic programs to authenticate using MIT Kerberos
```

Your Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM python:3.5.7-buster

ADD krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf
ADD krb5.keytab /etc/krb5.keytab

COPY requirements.txt .

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libsasl2-dev libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit openssl libkrb5-dev krb5-config krb5-user
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

*Note: `krb5-user` installation is interactive, you need to set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` to [make it unattended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39804070/7641078).*

Comment: Of course, with unattended installation, you get a default configuration which is probably not useful. You can preseed `debconf` with suitable configuration values (though see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=829671) or put your own `/etc/krb5.conf` to replace it.

Comment: Thank you @Eduardo Baitello